# Check url format not work php

Tags: php

when `$url` = `http://wwwgooglecom` , `http://www.googlecom`

It's will echo `OK` Why ?

```
if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) 
{
    echo "OK";
} 
else 
{
    echo "url incorrect";
}
?>
```

Comment: You've a double negative. Removing that would probably make things a bit more readable / understandable :P. Those URLs are in fact valid. So that's why it's saying `OK`.

Comment: could you show me for ex code ?

Comment: `if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))` would do exactly the same thing.

Comment: when use this code and `$url = https://www.google.com` it's will echo `url incorrect`

Comment: No it doesn't.... https://3v4l.org/dIup9 / https://3v4l.org/jj1X8

Comment: it's still ok on incorrect url https://3v4l.org/J6Vbj , https://3v4l.org/b4iJG

Comment: I will be explicit. `http://wwwgooglecom` and `http://www.googlecom` are _valid urls_, they are _not_ "incorrect". So of course you will get OK.

Comment: so whats wrong what did you expect the output be? those urls are correct

Comment: Remove the double negation, it makes it a lot better readable

Answer (score 0):

Basically an URL does not have to contain any dot symbol.

See this RFC : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-3.1

It does not specify to use a dot.

So urls like `https://example` or even `string://example` are valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$url = "http://wwwgooglecom";


$url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
echo("$url OK");
} else {
echo("$url is invalid");
}
?>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question

Comment: What exactly is your question?